# The phone case is black with silver... - which sentence is correct?

Tags: word-choice

> The phone case is black with silver additions.
>
> The phone case is black with silver decorations.
>
> The phone case is black with silver additives.
>
> The phone case is black with silver ornaments.
>
> The phone case is black with silver accessories.

The picture is something like this:

[image: Phone Cover]

Which sentences are correct? What's the difference between ornaments and decorations?

Comment: You are expected to use a dictionary to look up the meaning of words. What do you find when you look up "additions", "decorations" etc.

Comment: All the sentences are grammatically correct. You need to post an image of the [*black and silver phone cover*](https://www.google.it/search?q=black+and+silver+cell+case&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ15XF99XOAhUCSRoKHTeHCVoQ_AUICCgB#tbm=isch&q=black+and+silver+phone+cover), so users can say which sentence is more *accurate*

Comment: The phone is black and encrusted with bling http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bling

Comment: The (black) silver phone cover has crystals, bling; it's sparkly, it's studded/encrusted with swarovski ...

Comment: How on earth do you know the case is black?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the case we can't be sure, but probably it is described by

> The phone case is black with silver decorations

this implies a case that after it was constructed had some aesthetically pleasing designs added, perhaps by painting or adhesive decals: The case was decorated.

> The phone case is black with silver additions

Would describe the same physical situation but doesn't capture the thoughtful, artistic design implied by decorations.

> The phone case is black with silver ornaments

Might apply, but ornaments has the implication of something such as wire-work or jewelry conspicuously encrusting the case, I doubt that you are describing such a case

> The phone case is black with silver additives.

Implies that the silver was somehow mixed into the case's composition. More usually we apply this to chemical processes, such as those that produce processed foods. Something is mixed into the body of the substance, like anti-oxidents into some foodstuffs.

> The phone case is black with silver accessories

When I think of accessories it's the small additions to a person's outfit that bring it life: well chosen scarves, belts, earrings, broaches, tie-pins ... in other words, optional add-ons.

I'm really not sure what kind of accessories a phone case might have. Perhaps a detachable cover? In which case that might be silver I suppose.

Comment: What about the last sentence? I've edited my question. Nevertheless, thank you for your extensive answer.

Comment: I've inserted the photo.

Comment: What would you call silver? Decorations, ornaments, additions...? What about other elements?

Comment: My first reaction is that we need a whole new vocabulary to describe this :-)

Comment: This is silver diamante ornamentation with a ruby rhinestone bow accessory; bling in the best possible taste ;-)

Comment: Oh, that last comment is good, spot on, for me that's a perfect description.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., this sort of glittery, rhinestone-studded look is often called ***bling***.

When I did a Google image search on `phone case with bling`, the search returned the following images:

[image]

When I added the word *silver* to the search, the `phone case with silver bling` search returned the following:

[image]

which are pretty close to the phone case in your picture.

Comment: But what if I want to avoid the word "bling" and choose one of the words I asked about? To make it simple for a non-native speaker. I'm not a native English speaker, too. :)

Comment: @masterkomp - Then use _**crystals**_. Leave out those other nouns! I suppose _adornments_ could be changed to another part of speech: _The phone case is black and adorned with crystals._

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of a **swarovski** OR **sparkling phone case**. You can also describe it as a **jeweled phone cover**.

[image]

See [Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jeweled+phone+cases&biw=1366&bih=634&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjM4cP6_dXOAhUCNhoKHRoMCxMQ_AUIBygC) for some over-the-top **jeweled cases**. So garish they will make your eyes water.

> **[jeweled](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jeweled)**
>   (noun)
>
> 1. a cut and polished precious stone; gem.
> 2. a fashioned ornament for personal adornment, especially of a precious metal set with gems.
> 3. a precious possession.
>
> <sub>Dictionary.com</sub>

Comment: Great answer. One question: Do they make your eyes water because they sparkle so brilliantly and you're not wearing sunglasses? Or because you're crying with materialistic envy?

Comment: @J.R. the first, always the first.

Answer (score 1):

The additions are not silver, they are crystals.

> The phone case is black with crystal additions.
>   The phone case is black with crystal decorations.
>   The phone case is black with crystal accessories.
>   The phone case is black with crystal ornaments.

These four sentences are all correct in describing the iPhone.

An "additive" is *something* used in addition with *something else*

> gasoline additive
>   detergent additive

If you wanted to be pedantic, the Hello Kitty bow might be the only part considered to be an "ornament".

Comment: Of the four you list, I'd say that only _crystal decorations_ sounds natural. In particular, _crystal additions_ may be grammatically correct, but I think it sounds odd and unidiomatic. A better way to say it would probably be: _The phone case is black with crystals_ (or maybe _...is black and studded with crystals_).

Comment: @J.R. I agree "studded with crystals" is better but was trying to stay within the OP's wording.

Comment: I believe the O.P. is hoping to learn a natural way to express this. I think this is a case where it's better to _not_ stick with the O.P.'s wording.